# Redis connection is not being released back to the pool

Tags: java, redis, connection-pooling, jedis

```
private static StringRedisTemplate stringRedisTemplate = null;
```

private static JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = null;

```
    try {
        RedisSentinelConfiguration sentinelConfig;          
        JedisPoolConfig poolConf = getPoolConfig();
                    
        if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER"))) {
            log.info("Inside REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER " + EMSUtil.encode(System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER")));
            sentinelConfig = new RedisSentinelConfiguration().master(System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_MASTER"));
            String[] nodeArray = System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_NODES").split(",");
            log.info("Nodes " + EMSUtil.encode(System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_NODES")));
            List<RedisNode> redisList = new ArrayList<RedisNode>();
            if (nodeArray != null) {
                for (String node : nodeArray) {
                    String[] nodeAddrArry = node.split(":");
                    log.info("Node Info : " + EMSUtil.encode(nodeAddrArry[0]) + " : " + EMSUtil.encode(nodeAddrArry[1]));
                    if (nodeAddrArry != null) {
                        RedisNode redisNode = new RedisNode(nodeAddrArry[0], Integer.parseInt(nodeAddrArry[1]));
                        redisList.add(redisNode);
                    }
                }
            }
            sentinelConfig.setSentinels(redisList);
            connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(sentinelConfig, poolConf);
            
        } else {
            // Defining Jedis Configuration
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_NODES"))) {
                JedisPoolConfig poolConfig = new JedisPoolConfig();
                poolConfig.setMaxTotal(15);
                poolConfig.setTestOnBorrow(true);
                poolConfig.setTestOnReturn(true);
                connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(poolConfig);
                connectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
                connectionFactory.setHostName(System.getenv("REDIS_SENTINEL_NODES"));
                connectionFactory.setPort(6379);
                
                
            }
        }       
        if (connectionFactory != null) {
            connectionFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
            stringRedisTemplate = new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
            stringRedisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
            stringRedisTemplate.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
            stringRedisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();
            
    } catch (Throwable jce) {
        log.fatal("Redis server error", jce);

    }       
}

public static void setRedisKeyValue(String key, String value, String timestamp) {
    if(log.isTraceEnabled())
        log.trace("Entered in setRedisKeyValue "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    boolean automaticLicUpdate = EMSUtil.isAutomaticLicUpdate();
    if (automaticLicUpdate) {
        value += "&&" + timestamp;
        try {
            if (stringRedisTemplate != null) {
                stringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, value);
                log.debug("Value of redis value is...." + value);
            }

        } catch (Throwable jce) {
            log.fatal("Redish Server Connection Refused: Not able to connect Jedis server.............." ,  jce);

        }
    }
}
```

There is a loop where 400 keys are being updated, but since max pool size is specified as 15 so only 15 keys are updated in redis cache, why the connection is not released to the pool once the key is updated. Its sequential call, not multithreaded call. If I increase the cache size to 400 then there is no issue, but I do not want to increase the cache size.